# Removing specific string from a variable

Tags: powershell

I have a file which contains server names and ports

```
test1.abc.com[123],test2.abc.com[123],test3.abc.com[123],test4.abc.com[123]
```

I have to read the file and take only server names. I tried below and I'm able to get server names with ports separately but need only server names i.e, test1.abc.com etc.,

Code I tried:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Test\Servers.txt

foreach ($ServerName in $servers)
{
$ServerName = $ServerName -split(',')
}
```

With this I get individual server name with port. How to take out server name from it? Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regex using the `-replace` function to remove the port:

```
$servers = Get-Content D:\tmp.txt

foreach ($ServerName in $servers)
{
    $ServerName = $ServerName -split(',') -replace '\[\d+\]'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help Martin. It worked.  I have one more question related to it. Lets say i have just server names anand in for loop if i have to add port number to server then?

Comment: It realy depends on your needs. Usually you would parse the log first and get a list of objects containg the servername and the port so you can just assign a different name / port or query them. If you just want to add them, you can use simple string concat

Comment: Thanks buddy for the info